BigQuery, create table from partitioned data in an Amazon S3 bucket that is not in the supported hive style partitioned format
My data provider provides our data in a Hive partitioned format where the files (parquet files) are separated by year,month,date by folder
s3://bucket/my_data/YYYY/MM/DD/file.parquet
I have created the connection in my BigQuery project (that's already set up and working) but I am trying to create a single table to store this partitioned data. Just read up in Google's documentation that it has to be in a hive partitioned format with the keys indication the partition in the folder names. Is there a way around this or do I have to rename the partitioned folders to the supported format.
If not what's the best way to rename (or copy and rename) the folders? otherwise I will have to ask our data provider if they can make this change to the folder names instead...
